# Model is not generated from ARFIMA in R

Tags: r, forecasting, prediction, kalman-filter

I want to forecast ARFIMA with Kalman filter and not able to fit the arfima model into the Kalmanforecast.

```
 library(base)
 library(stats)
 library(parallel)
 library(forecast)
 sink(file='/home/nero/KF_arfima.log')
 f=COST$COST
 x=logb(p,10)
 # Start the clock!
 ptm <- proc.time()
 p=arfima(x[1:50], drange=c(0, 0.5),estim=c("mle"))
 pr <- KalmanForecast(2, p$model)
 y=x[51:52] 
 yhat=pr$pred #predicted value
 map=mean(abs((y - yhat)/y)) #MAPE
 proc.time() - ptm
 print(map)
```

I am getting the error

> Error in KalmanForecast(2, p$model) : invalid argument type"

I also check and found that there is no object called model. I lost three days to solve it. I tried with various R packages, but none of them has solved it. Please let me know how to fix it.

Data Sample:

```
Timestamp,COST
2015-09-21T00:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T00:06:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:12:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:18:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:24:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:30:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:36:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:42:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T00:48:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T00:54:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T01:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T01:06:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:12:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:18:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:24:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:30:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:36:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:42:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T01:48:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T01:54:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T02:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T02:06:00+00:00,8
2015-09-21T02:12:00+00:00,8
2015-09-21T02:18:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T02:24:00+00:00,8
2015-09-21T02:30:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T02:36:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T02:42:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T02:48:00+00:00,8
2015-09-21T02:54:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T03:06:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:12:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:18:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:24:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:30:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:36:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:42:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T03:48:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T03:54:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:06:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T04:12:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T04:18:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T04:24:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T04:30:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:36:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:42:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:48:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T04:54:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T05:00:00+00:00,6
2015-09-21T05:06:00+00:00,7
2015-09-21T05:12:00+00:00,7
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung I place the full code and also the data source.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're most of the way there, but I don't see how we can access the data. There are methods for posting data listed at the link I gave.

Comment: @gung I also fix the data source issue..

Comment: Is your data just an alternating sequence of 6, 7, 8? I doubt an ARFIMA model could suit it well.

Comment: OK, at this point I think we can migrate this to [SO] where it should be on topic. I will flag the moderators.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes the data is like this. Even if ARFIMA does not perform well, I need to see the error measure for further comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help file for `KalmanForecast` clearly describes what sort of model is required. The `arfima` function does not produce output of the required kind.

Rather than use `KalmanForecast`, you can use the `forecast` function from the **forecast** package to produce the forecasts. It also uses a Kalman filter to compute the forecasts.

If you really want to use the `KalmanForecast` to do the work, you will have to figure out how to create the `mod` argument yourself.

Comment: I changed the code like this but I am still getting the same error: `k=arfima(x[1:400], drange=c(0, 0.5),estim=c("mle"))`
`z=forecast(k,h=2)`
`pr <- KalmanForecast(2, z)` I check the model but it is different.

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. You can't use `KalmanForecast` unless you create the mod argument in the form described in the help file.

Comment: Thanks... now with forecast package its working. Initially, I searched the forecast package but did not find Kalman filter  :)